replace number words in spark sql using regex and consider case-insensitive
I want to replace all number words like One, ONE, one, ONE in pyspark sql query with 'anonymous number'. Consider case insensitive for regex_replace number words  and trying to preserve the case sensitivity of the other words on output. Do no not convert entire output to lower or upper.
SQL= """SELECT text
,
regex_replace(
text,
'(?i)\\b(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)\\b','anonymous number') as phrase
from
test_table;
"""

spark.sql(SQL)

but it is not working. Can you all please kindly provide solution.
INPUT: one Way is ALLowed and TWO way is not allowed. TRAffic has thREE colour Signals.
EXPECTED OUTPUT: anonymous number is ALLowed and anonymous number way is not allowed. TRAffic has anonymous number colour Signals.

If you use Python, just initialize SQL with raw string: SQL = r"""SELECT text...""", your current assignment treats the \\b in regexp as the literal letter b.
